# Why is Ruby whining about this unless set of parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

This is my statement:

```
unless (parameter.values.any? "" || parameter.values.any? 0 || parameter[:num_units].eql? 0 || parameter[:num_units].nil? || parameter[:num_units].empty?)
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
: syntax error, unexpected tINTEGER, expecting ')' ...? "" || parameter.values.any? 0 || parameter[:num_units].eql... ... ^
```

**Edit 1**

Basically what I am trying to do is to check to see if the value for any parameters that are passed in is either `nil`, `""` or `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parentheses around the arguments to the `.any?` functions:

```
(parameter.values.any?("") || parameter.values.any?(0) || parameter[:num_units].eql?(0) || parameter[:num_units].nil? || parameter[:num_units].empty?)
=> true
```

The parentheses around the entire line line are likely unnecessary too.

Comment: Perfect. Works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you explain *why* parentheses are necessary; specifically, why the cited syntax error was raised.

Comment: The interpreter is getting confused with all the chained "or", same as it is could be confusing to look at. For instance `a = var || 0` is valid syntax in Ruby, sets `a` to a `var` unless it is `nil`, in which case it sets it to `0`. Take that principle and apply it to the example. Is it asking if any? on `"" || 0` (which according to my example always compare `""` since it is never `nil`, or is it asking `if "" is nil then result of parameter.values.any?(0) will be used`. It doesn't really make sense, is obviously not intended, and confuses both people and Ruby alike.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous answer mentioned, parentheses... they make it more readable also. Despite that, this is a horrible conditional for a single line..

if you wanted to shorten it you could change it to this:

`unless (parameter.values & ["", 0]).any? || [0, nil, []].include?(parameter[:num_units])`

(the `[0, nil, []]` array assumes that the empty value of `parameter[:num_units]` you are checking for is an array - if it's a hash instead then obviously switch the comparison array for `[0, nil, {}]`